# Building android - how to load kernel image in mkbootimg command?

Tags: android, android-source, android-build

root@ubuntu:/media/Source/ICS_SOURCE# out/host/linux-x86/bin/mkbootimg --kernel zImage --ramdisk ramdisk.img.gz -o --boot.img
error: could not load kernel 'zImage'

i am getting this error again and again..

Where i have to put kernel image to run this command?? actually after build source code i didn't get boot.img!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You will not get the bootimage (`zImage` or `Image` from `arch/arm/boot` folder) file after compiling kernel.

move your mkbootimg binary to bin

```
sudo mv mkbootimg /bin
```

copy all the `zImage`, `ramdisk.img.gz` (when I compiled I used `ramdisk.img`) to a folder

Open terminal there

type

```
mkbootimg --kernel zImage --ramdisk ramdisk.img.gz -o --boot.img
```

Comment: I was unable to post a comment on your post, if this does not work please provide more info ..

Comment: i have created boot.img with your help, so what now how i update my tab with these files?? i have boot.img, zImage, ramdisk.img, system.img, userdata.img..

Comment: you have to flash it... I don't know how